Regex on snowflake to find value ends with '_' + number
I would like to return the table name with the format ends with '_'+ number
e.g. 'Sales_123', 'Employee_999999
I tried several format but just don't work on snowflake....
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%^_[0-9]$' ESCAPE '^'

Based on the knowledge I have, I know ^ here is for special char, _ to make it real character
and it need to be use with escape ^ in the end
The second, $ means end of the value.
I may be very wrong, please let me know how it works correctly.

Pretty much every RDMS is slightly, or not so slightly different, in the way they implement SQL. However all platforms document their SQL very well, so its a simple matter of reading the documentation for like on SQL Server and Snowflake to find out what you need to know.

You have to use rlike function for regex-based string searches. It is not possible with the like function
Documentation for your reference https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike
select distinct table_name
from information_schema.tables
where rlike(table_name, '\\w+_[0-9]+');

select count(distinct table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where table_name rlike '\\w+_[0-9]+';


Why do you need \\w in the regexp? They didn't say what has to be before the _number

table name with the format ends with '_'+ number e.g. 'Sales_123', 'Employee_999999 This is the example from question. Table name starts with the _.  With regards to \\w, we need to escape the backslashes if a single quotes format is used. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#specifying-regular-expressions-in-single-quoted-string-constants

Sure, removed it

Ah, didn't know that Snowflake has implicit anchors, so just _[0-9]+$ wouldn't work.

RLIKE allows for patterns, but both LIKE and RLIKE implicit anchor, so you need to allow prior or post tokens if you want them, thus
select 
    $1 as table_name,
    table_name rlike '_\\d+' as wrong_pattern,
    table_name rlike '.*_\\d+' as rlike_pattern_1,
    rlike(table_name, '.*_\\d+') as rlike_pattern_2,   
from values
('Sales_123'), 
('Employee_999999'),
('not_this'),
('not_this_also_123_');

gives:



TABLE_NAME
WRONG_PATTERN
RLIKE_PATTERN_1
RLIKE_PATTERN_2




Sales_123
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE


Employee_999999
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE


not_this
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE


not_this_also_123_
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE



